# Tweepy Oauth2 - missing_code/callback URI

Tags: python, authentication, oauth-2.0, tweepy

I have a basic understanding of auth2 and believe I am using the right protocol version (Oauth2 user context) to allow user login.

But I keep getting errors, probably because I'm missing knowledge and not understand some concepts.

I'm creating a basic web app with Tweepy.

I'm able to print and check the auth_url which when I paste in my browser, directs me as a user to authorize the app on twitter (but I get stuck on the redirect uri and in general get the error logged below):

Codebase:

```
import tweepy
import config


oauth2_user_handler = tweepy.OAuth2UserHandler(
    client_id="",
    redirect_uri="http://127.0.0.1:5000",
    scope=["tweet.write"],
    client_secret=""
)

auth_url = oauth2_user_handler.get_authorization_url()

access_token = oauth2_user_handler.fetch_token(f"{auth_url}")

client = tweepy.Client(f"{auth_url}")
```

The error message im getting:

```
"""
in parse_authorization_code_response
    raise MissingCodeError("Missing code parameter in response.")
oauthlib.oauth2.rfc6749.errors.MissingCodeError: (missing_code) Missing code parameter in response.
"""
```

A few side notes I have:

What website URL do I put in my app settings? (Do I need to spin up a server and get the URL from that dashboard?) How is the website URL related to the callback URI and how do they differ? this is my first time working with authentication & Twitter API.

Comment: Hey @Flaki, were you able to figure this out? I'm stuck on the same issue.

Comment: Same issue, were you able to arrive at a resolution